# Compile all rustdoc comments in project folder into single markdown file

Tags: rust, rustdoc

Let's say I have the following directory structure in a VSCode project:

```
- MY_EXAMPLES
 - Example_1
   - src
    - main.rs
   - Cargo.lock
   - Cargo.toml
 - Example_2
   - src
    - main.rs
   - Cargo.lock
   - Cargo.toml
```

Now I want to compile the comments from all `main.rs` files. In this case, that'd be `MY_EXAMPLES/Example_1/src/main.rs` and `MY_EXAMPLES/Example_2/src/main.rs`. Note that I would like this solution to scale, so I could automatically compile the comments if I had 10 or 20 Example_X folders.

*MY_EXAMPLES/Example_1/src/main.rs*

```rust
/// My notes on Example 1 that I'd like to add to my README.md
fn main(){
//..
}
```

*MY_EXAMPLES/Example_2/src/main.rs*

```rust
/// My notes on Example 2 that I'd like to add to my README.md
fn main(){
//..
}
```

Running:

```
C:\Users\Primary User\Desktop\MY_EXAMPLES> cargo doc
```

should create a README.md file that looks like:

---

#### Example_1

My notes on Example 1 that I'd like to add to my README.md

#### Example_2

My notes on Example 2 that I'd like to add to my README.md

---

So our general template for the README.md content is something like:

```
### Project Rootdir
rustdoc comments
```

Does rustdoc have any kind of templating system, similar to that of JSDoc, etc?
I've also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59150327/generate-markdown-docs-with-rustdoc) similar question, which is currently without an answer.